# How to calculate Standard Deviation in Python when x and P(x) are known

Tags: python, math, scipy, statistics, stat

I have the following data and I wish to calculate the standard deviation. The value of x and probability of x is given.

| x | P(x) |
| --- | --- |
| -2,000 | 0.1 |
| -1,000 | 0.1 |
| 0 | 0.2 |
| 1000 | 0.2 |
| 2000 | 0.3 |
| 3000 | 0.1 |

I know how to calculate it manually: by calculating the `Var(x)` by `E[x^2] - (E[x])^2` and then taking `Sqrt(Var(x))`.

[This is how it is done manually]
[image]

How do you calculate it in python?

Comment: While the method in the image is fine mathematically, it can be unreliable in floating point arithmetic. If, for example, the mean is large and the variation between entries small, then due to rounding error the variance can be negative! Its better to compute E(X) then E((X-E(X))*(X-E(X))) rather than E(X*X) - E(X)*E(X)

Comment: Oh okay. That sounds like a better approach. Thanks @dmuir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify, the standard deviation of [1000, 2000, 3000, 0, -1000, -2000] is indeed 1707.8 if assuming all 6 terms have **equal** probability distribution.

However in the post, the 6 terms have unequal probability distribution [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1]

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
{'x':-2000, 'P(x)':0.1}, 
{'x':-1000, 'P(x)':0.1}, 
{'x':0, 'P(x)':0.2}, 
{'x':1000, 'P(x)':0.2}, 
{'x':2000, 'P(x)':0.3}, 
{'x':3000, 'P(x)':0.1} ])

df['E(x)'] = df['x'] * df['P(x)']        # E(x) = x . P(x)
df['E(x^2)'] = df['x']**2 * df['P(x)']   # E(x^2) = x^2 . P(x)
variance = df['E(x^2)'].sum() - df['E(x)'].sum() **2
std_dev = variance **0.5
display(df)
print('Standard Deviation is: {:.2f}'.format(std_dev))
```

Output

```
    x       P(x)    E(x)    E(x^2)
0   -2000   0.1     -200.0  400000.0
1   -1000   0.1     -100.0  100000.0
2   0       0.2     0.0     0.0
3   1000    0.2     200.0   200000.0
4   2000    0.3     600.0   1200000.0
5   3000    0.1     300.0   900000.0
Standard Deviation is: 1469.69
```

To confirm, you can go to https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/standard-deviation-calculator.html

[image]

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I was looking for. I thought python or scipy would have an inbuilt function that could take in both lists and give me the required result. Thank you so much @Gold79.

Comment: That's great! Do you know how to find miu? `df['E(x)'].sum() / df['P(x)'].sum()` output `800` More maths fanatics should upvote your question! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import math

df['x_squared'] = df['x']**2
df['E_of_x_squared'] = df['x_squared'] * df['P(x)']
df['E_of_x'] = df['x'] * df['P(x)']

sum_E_x_square = df['E_of_x_squared'].values.sum()
square_of_E_x_sum = df['E_of_x'].values.sum()**2

var = sum_E_x_square - square_of_E_x_sum

std_dev = math.sqrt(var)

print('Standard Deviation is: ' + str(std_dev))
```

Comment: Not sure if this is right. I should be getting 1469.69 as standard dev.

Comment: The Standard Deviation of [1000, 2000, 3000, 0,  -1000, -2000] is 1707.825128

Comment: I understand that.  But can you take a look at the manual method I have attached along with the question? It has taken the P(x) {Distribution of x values} into consideration and found out the std dev.

Comment: the manual calculation 1469.69 is correct because all 6 terms have unequal probability distribution.. @ShivamRoy your code yields the correct answer 1469.69 too!

Comment: @Gold79 Hi, yes I realised the probability distribution part later, thank you. You have written an amazing answer.